# Keras - Confusion about number of input layer nodes

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, sequential

So, when input_dim=3, it means that the input to a layer is three nodes right?
But what about when input_shape attribute is used and there are more than one values?
For example:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(82, 82, 3)))
```

Here, the convolutional layer has 32 output nodes, but how many input nodes does it have?

model.summary() gives this:

```
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 80, 80, 32)        896       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 80, 80, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 40, 40, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 38, 38, 32)        9248      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_2 (Activation)    (None, 38, 38, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 19, 19, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 17, 17, 64)        18496     
_________________________________________________________________
activation_3 (Activation)    (None, 17, 17, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 8, 8, 64)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 4096)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 64)                262208    
_________________________________________________________________
activation_4 (Activation)    (None, 64)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 64)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 65        
_________________________________________________________________
activation_5 (Activation)    (None, 1)                 0         
=================================================================
Total params: 290,913
Trainable params: 290,913
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here Input_shape is used for images :

Your example contain images shape 82x82x3 ==20172 which is equal to input node:

** How would you check this **

```
print(model.summary())
```

model.summary gives you complete detail of each layer

Comment: So there are 20,172 input nodes?

Comment: Yes I did, I have added the O/P of that to the question

Comment: I think you know data we feed inside the model is always 1D  .Here images contain  3D show we always convert into 1D .You can check this by flatten layer  inside your model which look like (8,8,64)>>>8x8x64==4096 .similarly for input this pattern is follow

Comment: If you fimilar with digit mnist dataset on kaggle which is given format of csv file ,not in the format of images .where csv file dimension are (60000,784) 60000 show no of images and 784 show no fo column .if you convert 784 dim into shape then it will  look like 28X28 i think that's enough for understand.